# Is it possible to return place reviews mentioning certain keywords in the text?

Tags: json, google-maps, web-services, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I know I can return a JSON array of up to 5 reviews. If I can return just 5 reviews that include only certain keywords that would be fine. Is it possible?

If not, perhaps I could generate a request that returns all the reviews for a place, then perform the keyword filter on the results.

I understand the business owner may return all reviews via My Business API, but I will not have My Business access for the places. I believe I can get more than 5 results with a premium plan, but assume that will get pretty expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right the only way to get all reviews is via Google My Business API.The Places API at the moment provides only 5 reviews doesn't matter Premium or Standard plan.

There are a couple of feature requests in Google issue tracker you might be interested in:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825957

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821903

Note these requests are pretty old, Google didn't set high priority on them. You can star them to express your interest and subscribe to further notifications.

Hope this answer clarifies your doubt.